# 64 bit 12.04 too much for 1 GB RAM?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, wubi, 32-bit

New install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit is painfully slow and freezes on a Dell 5150 desktop. It has dual core 2.8 GHz Pentium 4 processors and 1 GB RAM. Usage is over 700 MB with just the desktop running.

I installed using Wubi and used the 64 bit kernel by mistake. Our other machine is flying with the 32 bit and has 2 GB RAM.
Could the 64 bit be the reason for the freezing?
Would upgrading the RAM alone fix it?
How could a reinstall of the 32 bit be done - would Wubi simply overwrite the previous installation ?

Alternatively am I barking up the wrong tree entirely.
My technical knowledge is zero so please go easy - but I do love Linux. Wish I had found it years ago.
Graphics from pci devices in hardinfo

Good machine 32 bit. Intel 82G33/31 memory 512KB 256MB(32bit prefetch) 1MB (32bit non prefetch)
Slow machine 64 bit  AMD/ATI RV370 (no memory entry) 32 MB prefetch  64kB non prefetch

Comment: This is probably more related to your graphics card than the RAM. Please [edit] your post and mention the graphics cards (especially their memory) of both computers. Also, there is no reason to use the default (heavy) interface, there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

1 GB is just barely enough to run Ubuntu, especially if you have an integrated graphics card stealing some of that.  32 bit might be *slightly* better, but you really just need more ram.  As an alternative, xubuntu or lubuntu need less ram.